# How do I remove unwanted, untrack directories from my git branch?

Tags: git, git-untracked

For some reason I have untracked folders in my git branch that have nothing to do with my current directory. They seem to be mostly parallel directories.

I have no clue why but I've tried to use `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard >> .gitignore` and `git clean -d -f -f`.
Not sure if it is something up with my repo or what.

The only files that should exist are `index.html` and `scripts.js`

[image: git status]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a `.git` folder in the *parent* directory of the one including `script.js`.

If you do (and don't care about its history), remove it, then initialize a git repo in your current folder (where script.js is)

```
git init .
git status
```

Then you should see only your files, and not parent folders.

Comment: Thanks that was it!  If you have a moment can you explain why this may have been the case? I guess I must have used git init before in the wrong directory?

Comment: @Zamir Yes: I suppose this was the case: a git init . done one folder above the one you wanted.